# Plot of ND solve differential equation with another parameter

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation numerically but I need to vary y0 for my plot and view result for constant x. I can solve my equation normally as I expected:but I can't get result when I try for my real purpose as you can see

```
`\[Sigma] = 1;
n = 23.04;
Rop = y[x];
R = 0.5;
sz = R/(Rop + R);
F = -n*\[Sigma]*y[x]*(1 - 2*sz);
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == F, y[0] == 0.8}, y, {x, 0, 0.07}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 0.07}, PlotRange -> All,]`


`[Sigma] = 1;
 n = 23.04;
 Rop = y[x];
 R = 0.5;
 sz = R/(Rop + R);
 F = -n*\[Sigma]*y[x]*(1 - 2*sz);
 y0 = 0.8;
 \!\(\*
 ButtonBox["Array",
 BaseStyle->"Link",
 ButtonData->"paclet:ref/Array"]\)[s, 140]
 i = 1;
 For[i < 140,
  s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == F, y[0] == y0}, y, {x, 0, 0.07}]
      Plot[Evaluate[y[] /. s], x = 0.07, {y0, 0.8, 2.2}] // print
      y0 == y0 + i*0.01];`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variety of typos or misunderstandings

```
\[Sigma] = 1;
n = 23.04;
Rop = y[x];
R = 0.5;
sz = R/(Rop + R);
F = -n*\[Sigma]*y[x]*(1 - 2*sz);
y0 = 0.8;
For[i = 1, i < 140, i++, 
  s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == F, y[0] == y0}, y, {x, 0, 0.07}]; 
  Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 0.07}] // Print;
  y0 = y0 + i*0.01
];
```

Go through that and compare it a character at a time against your original.
After you have figured out why each of the changes were made then you can try to decide whether to put your Button back in that or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
you mean differential equation can't be plotted in this way? I'm not sure you get my idea. I'm going to get just the last data of NDsolve x=0.07 and plot it for {y0,0.8,90}

Comment: I don't know what "in this way" is and I'm sure I don't get your idea given only the words you originally wrote. Maybe this? Table[(y[x] /. NDSolve[{y'[x]==F, y[0]==y0}, y, {x, 0, 0.07}][[1, 1]]) /. x->0.07, {y0, .8, 90, .01}] but I can't guess how you want that plotted. Imagine the reader knows nothing about what is in your mind and can only look at the words you wrote. If you can imagine that then perhaps you can think how a problem might be described.

Comment: I'm new programmer and not used to ask questions so I should give my apologies for my mistakes. "in this way"= I have NDsolve of my equation across range(0,0.07) but I need just the value of y in x=0.07 for variety of y0 so I write for loop but as I try to give the Plot y0 range I have several error. I try FindMinimum and Last to get out the y[0.07] inside the for loop but that doesn't work at all that leads me that may be NDsolve can't be used in this way. Could you offer me any function that can read NDsolve in correct way? Thanks For your help again

Comment: Replace everything from and including the y0=0.8 to the end of my code with sol = Table[y[x]/. NDSolve[{y'[x]==F, y[0]==y0}, y, {x,0,0.07}][[1]], {y0,.8,.9,.01}]; sol/.x->.07 and it gives you y[.07] for y0=.8, y[.07] for y0=.81,etc. That gives you "just the value of y in x=0.07 for variety of y0" This is pretty much what I showed in my previous comment, a list of the y[x] values at x=.07 for each y0 value. You can also Plot[sol, {x, 0, 0.07}]